# Unresolved reference.None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: when using protobuf plugin in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, protobuf-java

I'm using `com.google.protobuf` gradle plugin in my project for generating java classes from proto files.
Below is my build.gradle which works fine.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18'
  }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.18'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation('io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.45.1')
    implementation('io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.45.1')
    implementation('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.45.1')
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.0"
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.45.1'
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
      grpc {}
    }
  }
}
```

I'm rewriting the build into kotlin dsl as below -

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18")
    }
}
plugins {
    java
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.18"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


dependencies {
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.45.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.45.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.45.1")
//    implementation("org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

protobuf {

    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.45.1"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
```

when I do `gradle clean compileJava` I get below error -

> $ gradle clean compileJava
>
> > Configure project :
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:50:15: Expecting an element
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:41:5: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> > public fun ProtobufConfigurator.protoc(action: ExecutableLocator.() -> Unit): Unit defined in com.google.protobuf.gradle
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:45:9: Unresolved reference: grpc
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:46:13: Unresolved reference: artifact
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:49:5: Unresolved reference: generateProtoTasks
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:50:9: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> > public inline fun  Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun BooleanArray.all(predicate: (Boolean) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun ByteArray.all(predicate: (Byte) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun CharArray.all(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun CharSequence.all(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
> > public inline fun DoubleArray.all(predicate: (Double) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun FloatArray.all(predicate: (Float) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun IntArray.all(predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun LongArray.all(predicate: (Long) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun ShortArray.all(predicate: (Short) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun UByteArray.all(predicate: (UByte) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun UIntArray.all(predicate: (UInt) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun ULongArray.all(predicate: (ULong) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun UShortArray.all(predicate: (UShort) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun  Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.all(predicate: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
> > public inline fun  Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.sequences
> > public inline fun  ComponentMetadataHandler.all(): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> > public inline fun ComponentMetadataHandler.all(rule: KClass): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> > public inline fun ComponentMetadataHandler.all(rule: KClass, configureAction: Action): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> > public inline fun  ComponentMetadataHandler.all(configureAction: Action): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> > e: /home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts:51:13: Unresolved reference: grpc
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file '/home/rajkumar/Coding/java/grpc/grpc-complete-course/grpc-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts' line: 50
> - What went wrong:
>   Script compilation errors:
>
>   Line 50:         all()*.plugins {
>   ^ Expecting an element
>
>   Line 41:     protoc {
>   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>   public fun ProtobufConfigurator.protoc(action: ExecutableLocator.() -> Unit): Unit defined in com.google.protobuf.gradle
>
>   Line 45:         grpc {
>   ^ Unresolved reference: grpc
>
>   Line 46:             artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.45.1"
>   ^ Unresolved reference: artifact
>
>   Line 49:     generateProtoTasks {
>   ^ Unresolved reference: generateProtoTasks
>
>   Line 50:         all()*.plugins {
>   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>   public inline fun  Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun BooleanArray.all(predicate: (Boolean) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun ByteArray.all(predicate: (Byte) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun CharArray.all(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun CharSequence.all(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.text
>   public inline fun DoubleArray.all(predicate: (Double) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun FloatArray.all(predicate: (Float) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun IntArray.all(predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun LongArray.all(predicate: (Long) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun ShortArray.all(predicate: (Short) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun UByteArray.all(predicate: (UByte) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun UIntArray.all(predicate: (UInt) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun ULongArray.all(predicate: (ULong) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun UShortArray.all(predicate: (UShort) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun  Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.all(predicate: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
>   public inline fun  Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.all(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.sequences
>   public inline fun  ComponentMetadataHandler.all(): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>   public inline fun ComponentMetadataHandler.all(rule: KClass): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>   public inline fun ComponentMetadataHandler.all(rule: KClass, configureAction: Action): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>   public inline fun  ComponentMetadataHandler.all(configureAction: Action): ComponentMetadataHandler defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>
>   Line 51:             grpc {}
>   ^ Unresolved reference: grpc
>
> 7 errors
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s

How can I fix the error? I don't know how to do that in kotlin dsl?